# Rails How to calculate Running Total on a View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making a financial application and I would like to display a running total for the balance in my view, similar to how most online banking platforms work.  I am not sure how to do this.  I store credits as positive numbers and debits as negative numbers in my database.  So I would basically need to sort by date, and add the amounts cumulatively for a new column in my view to display the running balance.

In my model I have defined this, based on lots of searching here:

```
    def running_total
       running_total = self.inject(0) { |sum, p| sum + p.amount }
    end
```

But it does not seem to be working.  I get the error:

> undefined method `inject' for #<Transaction:0x00007f15bd9dae70>
>   Did you mean?  inspect

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

## Updates:

Per the advice of @spickermann, I have made some updates to my code, and the running balance is now being calculated properly when creating a new transaction or modifying an old one, but I am still having trouble getting the subsequent records to update the running balance when editing a previous transaction.  As seen in the console, the previous_transaction method is getting fired to select transactions later than the one I'm editing, but the value is not getting updated in the database.

**transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
    attr_accessor :trx_type

    #default_scope { order('trx_date, id DESC') }
    validates_presence_of :trx_type, :message => "Please select debit or credit"
    validates :trx_date, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
    validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
    validates :memo, length: { maximum: 500 }

    before_save :convert_amount, :set_running_balance
    after_create :update_account_balance_new
    after_update :update_account_balance_edit
    after_destroy :update_account_balance_destroy
    after_save :recalculate_running_balance, on: :update

    scope :desc, -> { order('trx_date, id DESC') }

    # Determine the transaction_type for existing records based on amount
    def transaction_type
        if !new_record?
            if self.amount >= 0
                return ['Credit', 'credit']
            else
                return ['Debit', 'debit']
            end
        else
            return ['Debit', 'debit']
        end
    end

private

    def set_running_balance
        previous_balance = previous_transaction.try(:running_balance) || 0
        self.running_balance = previous_balance + amount
    end

    def recalculate_running_balance
        # this will recursively trigger the `recalculate_next_running_balance` 
        # callback on the following transactions and thereby update all later 
        # transactions
        next_transaction.try(:save)
    end

    def previous_transaction
        scope = Transaction.where(account: account).order(:id)
        scope = scope.where('id < ?', id) if persisted?

        scope.last
    end

    def next_transaction
        return if new_record?

        Transaction.where(account: account).where('id > ?', id).order(:id).first
    end

    def convert_amount
        if self.trx_type == "debit"
            self.amount = -self.amount.abs
        end
    end

    def update_account_balance_new
        @account = Account.find(account_id)
        @account.update_attributes(current_balance: @account.current_balance + amount)
    end

    def update_account_balance_edit
        @account = Account.find(account_id)
        if saved_change_to_amount?
            @account.update_attributes(current_balance: @account.current_balance - amount_was + amount)
        end
    end

    def update_account_balance_destroy
        @account = Account.find(account_id)
        @account.update_attributes(current_balance: @account.current_balance - amount_was)
    end

end
```

**Console**

```
Processing by TransactionsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9GuEIo7a7OUAMA3O26keE8zOlptfzd+F9Enp43hl0A7sh/5ioTDAud0AzLriOWiquU+wbyOoDgK8o6z9OZyLzA==", "transaction"=>{"trx_type"=>"debit", "trx_date(1i)"=>"2018", "trx_date(2i)"=>"3", "trx_date(3i)"=>"26", "description"=>"Meijer", "amount"=>"100.00", "memo"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Transaction", "account_id"=>"3", "id"=>"21"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = $1 AND "accounts"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Transaction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."account_id" = $1 AND "transactions"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["account_id", 3], ["id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Transaction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."account_id" = 3 AND (id < 21) ORDER BY "transactions"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "transactions" SET "amount" = $1, "running_balance" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "transactions"."id" = $4  [["amount", "-100.0"], ["running_balance", "1800.0"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-26 15:14:53.354282"], ["id", 21]]
  Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_was` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `attribute_before_last_save` instead. (called from update_account_balance_edit at /home/sitheris/dev/railsapps/olubalance/app/models/transaction.rb:85)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?` instead. (called from update_account_balance_edit at /home/sitheris/dev/railsapps/olubalance/app/models/transaction.rb:85)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed_attributes` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes.transform_values(&:first)` instead. (called from update_account_balance_edit at /home/sitheris/dev/railsapps/olubalance/app/models/transaction.rb:85)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "current_balance" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3  [["current_balance", "1200.0"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-26 15:14:53.358782"], ["id", 3]]
NEXT TRANSACTION
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."account_id" = 3 AND (id > 21) ORDER BY "transactions"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (3.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/accounts/3/transactions/21
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the running total in the database next to the debits and credits.

Why?

1. You do not want to recalculate the running total on every page view.
2. You do not want to calculate the current running total starting from a 0 years ago when all you want is the today's balance.

That said: Optimize for reading your data and calculate the balance when you save a new debit or credit row into your database.

To implement a calculation-on-save just basically need to change two things:

A migration to add a balance column and to backfill existing records. The format of the column (integer, decimal) depends on your setup, same for how to scope the backfill (I assume by a user):

```
def up
  add_column :transactions, :balance, :integer

  # This is just a quick and dirty implementation and will run very 
  # slowly. But for a few thousand records it might be fast enough.
  User.find_each { |user| user.transactions.first.try(:save) }

  change_column_null :transactions, :balance, false
end

def down
  drop_column :transactions, :balance
end
```

And two callback in your model:

```
before_save :set_running_balance
after_save :recalculate_running_balance, on: :update

private

def set_running_balance
  previous_balance = previous_transaction_for_user.try(:balance) || 0
  self.balance = previous_balance + amount
end

def recalculate_running_balance
  # this will recursively trigger the `recalculate_next_running_balance` 
  # callback on the following transactions and thereby update all later 
  # transactions
  next_transaction_for_user.try(:save)
end

def previous_transaction_for_user
  scope = Transaction.where(user: user).order(:id)
  scope = scope.where('id < ?', id) if persisted?

  scope.last
end

def next_transaction_for_user
  return if new_record?

  Transaction.where(user: user).where('id > ?', id).order(:id).first
end
```

With these changes, you should be able to present a running balance even on paginated or filtered pages with a simple `<%= transaction.balance %>`.

Comment: thank you so much for the example.  With this app being a simple place where users can balance their accounts like a handwritten check register, I do want to allow editing of transactions, but I’m a bit lost on how to approach the updating of running balances for all later transactions. Could you help a rails newbie get started? I’m mainly stuck on syntax of doing what I need to do. Much thanks!

Comment: @odinsride: I updated my answer to address your requirement to be able to update existing amounts.

Comment: thanks very much, I would have pulled my hair out trying to come up with this! It covers some things I haven’t yet learned so I will read up a bit :) Thank you again!

Comment: please see my updates in the original post. I am having difficulty with the subsequent transactions running balance getting updated.  Thank you!

Comment: I am a bit confused about your attributes names, there are `current_balance` and `running_balance`. Because the original question is solved I would suggest starting a new question with the new problem.

Comment: Current_balance is stored with the account model, which is updated after any transaction is made or updated for the account. Running_balance is stored in the transaction model. I will post a new question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `Transaction` is one single transaction for a user, you'd want to do something like:

`current_user.transactions.pluck(:amount).sum`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion about using pluck but I couldn't get it to work.  I may consider moving this logic to a database column but I feel that would be more complex than the solution I came up with. I ended up doing this in my view to achieve what I need.  If there's a better way of doing this in the model or somewhere else I'm open to advice. Thanks!

```
<% @running_balance = 0 %>
<% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
    <% @running_balance = @running_balance + transaction.amount %>
    <tr class="row m-0">
        <td class="col-sm-1 text-center"><%= link_to transaction.id, [transaction.account, transaction] %></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1 text-center"><%= transaction.trx_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %></td>
        <td class="col-sm-4"><%= transaction.description %></td>
        <td class="col-sm-2 text-right"><%= if transaction.amount >= 0 then number_to_currency(transaction.amount) end %></td>
        <td class="col-sm-2 text-right"><%= if transaction.amount < 0 then "(" + number_to_currency(transaction.amount.abs) + ")" end %></td>
        <td class="col-sm-2 text-right"><%= number_to_currency(@running_balance) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As I wrote before: This only works if you show all transactions since the account was opened or since it had a balance of 0 of other reasons on the one page. As soon as you start with pagination, filters or flexible time range you will not be able anymore to show a correct running balance with this calculation in the view.

Comment: You’re right about this. I ran into the issue today when adding pagination :). I had tried storing the value in DB but got overwhelmed when I realized for example editing a transaction from 3 days ago would require recalculating the running total for all transactions entered afterward. I’m still on the fence as to how to approach this.